# How can I spin the wheel in a counterclockwise direction using a hand gesture? i have used flutter_fortune_wheel library

Tags: flutter

I'm currently facing an issue with the flutter_fortune_wheel package - I am unable to spin the wheel counterclockwise. I need this functionality because the default hand gesture/panning effect is not working smoothly. As a workaround, I plan to use my own GestureDetector to create smooth swipe actions for spinning the wheel. Does anyone have an idea of how to spin the wheel counterclockwise using only this package?

Package Link: https://github.com/kevlatus/flutter_fortune_wheel